# get value of a date time picker using php

Tags: php, html, datetimepicker

This code is an html represent a Date picker control on the form, i want to get the value in order to insert it to the Mysql DB, im using Php

i tried something like:
       $_POST[i dont know what to include here]

thanks in advance

```
<li class="form-line form-line-column" id="id_10">
    <label class="form-label-top" id="label_10" for="input_10"> National ID :<span class="form-required">*</span> </label>
    <div id="div" class="form-input-wide"><span class="form-sub-label-container">
      <input class="form-textbox validate[required]" id="q10_10[day]" name="day1" type="tel" size="2" maxlength="2" value="23" />
      <span class="date-separate">&nbsp;/</span>
      <label class="form-sub-label" for="q10_10[day]" id="sublabel_day"> Day </label>
      </span><span class="form-sub-label-container">
        <input class="form-textbox validate[required]" id="q10_10[month]" name="month1" type="tel" size="2" maxlength="2" value="02" />
        <span class="date-separate">&nbsp;/</span>
      <label class="form-sub-label" for="q10_10[month]" id="sublabel_month"> Month </label>
        </span><span class="form-sub-label-container">
          <input class="form-textbox validate[required]" id="birth_date" name="year1" type="tel" size="4" maxlength="4" value="2013" />
      <label class="form-sub-label" for="birth_date" id="sublabel_year"> Year </label>
          </span><span class="form-sub-label-container"><img alt="Pick a Date" id="input_10_pick" src="images/calendar.png" align="absmiddle" />
      <label class="form-sub-label" for="input_10_pick"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </label>
          </span> </div>
  </li>

$natdate = date_create(sprintf('%d/%d/%d', $_POST['year1'], $_POST['month1'], $_POST['day1']);

 $sql="INSERT INTO memdata(NatDate)
VALUES('$natdate')
```

When i try this i get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Day :  $_POST["day1"]
Month: $_POST["month1"]
Year:  $_POST["year1"]
```

Take a look at this Example:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure but maybe it should be :

```
$date = $_POST['day1'].'/'.$_POST['month1'].'/'.$_POST['year1'];
```

`i have concat the day , month and year together.`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL date field accept date in Y-m-d format.

Try

```
$date = $_POST['year1'].'/'.$_POST['month1'].'/'.$_POST['day1'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get the data, validate that it's a proper date and format it so that you can pass it to MySQL (ideally through a PDO).

```
$date = date_create(sprintf('%d/%d/%d', $_POST['year1'], $_POST['month1'], $_POST['day1']);
```

Comment: @adictee The recommended way of connecting to a database in PHP - http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php.

Comment: $natdate = date_create(sprintf('%d/%d/%d', $_POST['year1'], $_POST['month1'], $_POST['day1']);

 $sql="INSERT INTO memdata(NatDate)
VALUES('$natdate')
When i try this i get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'